# How can I properly export a java project as runnable jar?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, export, rmi

I'm trying to learn RMI API in java. Everything finally seems to be working; My server is up and running, my client can connect.
But when I export the project, from Eclipse, as a runnable jar with the Client as launch configuration, now this jar can't connect to my running server. I get an `AccessControlException`.

```
    if (System.getSecurityManager() == null) {
        System.setProperty("java.security.policy", "src/mySecurity");
        System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());
    }
```

Both the client and server has these as the first lines in their main methods. So I think they can't find the 'mySecurity' file after I've exported the project as a jar? What can I do?

**EDIT:** When I access .png files in my projects, I do this `MyClass.class.getResource("/resources/myImage.png")` That works fine when exported as a jar. But as I understand it, only .java files are supposed to go in the `src` folder of my project? But whatever is outside the src folder is not included in the jar file. (note that myImage.png is located in src).

So currently I export the jar and place it in a folder  with a resources folder in it(which I copied from my IDE workspace). Is this the way I'm supposed to do it, or can I in fact export my project as a executable jar with access resources on the same level with src?

Comment: Silly title, fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Run your JVMs with

```
-Djava.security.debug=access,failure,policy
```

The `policy` part shows you exactly what policy files are being loaded. The rest helps debug all `AccessControlExceptions` and their causes, and shows the protection domains that are in effect at each one, and the associated policy file in each case.

Comment: That produces a whole lot of giberrish that I don't know how to read. What am I hoping to find in here, though? Clearly the problem is with exporting my project.

Comment: It tells you whether the JVM has found your policy file, which is what you actually need to know. If it has, you've exported your project correctly and your problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: It has not, I know that for a fact. It works if I  put `mySecurity` in a `src` folder on the same level as the jar. After long time of working with this it has just now become clear to me what my problem really is, I feel the edit makes that very clear. There seems to be quite a few duplicates out there with accepted answers but still nothing quite to my liking :/

Comment: `System.setProperty("java.security.policy", "src/mySecurity");` it's looking for that file in the user directory. But it shouldn't, because only the .jar should be in the user.dir! Can I not change the string to look 'inside the jar'?

Comment: The `src` directory isn't there at deployment time. Only in your IDE. Don't put things there.

Comment: But can I then export my project as an executable jar? (if my resources aren't in `src`)